# Monotouch memory view controller problems

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, instruments

I have a problem with the memory consumption of my app I hope you can help me with this, I have a Navigation Controller with maybe 10 controllers to navigate forward or backward, I'm using  Instruments to check for the memory allocations (also used the mtouch profiler), when I navigate forward (1st time) obviously the memory consumed by the app increases .. but when i click on the standard back button of the nav controller the memory stills being the same amount and worst of all if I go forward again the memory increases more (i.e.: homeVC 10mb, VC1 = 10.5mb, back to homeVC = 10.5 mb, forward to VC1 = 11mb), yes the memory is increasing while I still navigating through the VCs. In this scenario I have the following questions:

- What is the behavior of the app on the standard Back button of the nav controller (it executes a PopViewControllerAnimated?).
- PopViewControllerAnimated and the other Pop methods of the navController should release the memory consumed by the dissapearing VC?
- If the Pop methods of the navcontrollers don't release the memory of the app, when I should dispose my disappearing VCs to avoid consuming so much memory? (I want to know the best work of manage the memory in the mono touch apps, maybe use the DidReceiveMemoryWarning method? or there are another places when i can manage the release of the memory of my app).

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds suspiciously similar to this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1889

You can work around it by fetching the ViewControllers property of the navigation controller once in a while.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How/why does that help? Where to fetch ViewControllers property, how often... some code would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex42: The bug report explains why it helps. How often: if you can determine when a view controller is being popped, you should do it then. Otherwise the "once in a while" really depends on your app - I wouldn't worry though, because it will only leak as long as you pop but don't push view controllers, and you can't pop indefinitely without pushing once in a while too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you use when you allocate and push your VC?

What I'm guessing is happening is you aren't releasing it after you allocate it, so when the NavigationController releases it when you press the Back button the retain count is still +1.